# Can't we delete directly delete/vote to delete before closing a question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-delete

Can't we just delete/vote to delete before even closing a question? Especially those spam question and questions from a junk user?

Comment: Voting and down and running away witout comment is new kind of heroism :P

Comment: -9 ?? one more -1 please ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only moderators have that power.  Only moderators *should* have that power.

This isn't to say that I don't agree with the premise - that content that is purely spam should be deleted on sight - but there's a lot of room for abuse.  I wouldn't feel entirely comfortable with someone being able to blanket delete stuff without them being *very* sure that it should go.  Only people right now that can do that are the moderators.

If you flag content as spam that actually is spam, then it will get acted on much faster, and given enough flags, the content may be deleted automatically by the system.

I see no reason to rush the process, since crap content doesn't stay up for very long at all.

Answer (score 7):

The process is to flag spam to delete it rather than voting.

The flagging process imposes a -100 rep penalty on the spammers account and also provides data for the anti-spam processing systems. It can also lead to the spammers account itself being deleted if it's only been used for spamming.

So it's much better to flag.